# Why In jitsi i am not able to access class of one package into another package its throws ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java

Any one help me,
I am calling one method **NewAccountDialog** of package `net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.main.account` into `SimpleAccountRegistrationActivator` class of another package `net.java.sip.communicator.plugin.simpleaccreg` but it throws following exceptions......

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/java/sip/communicator/impl/gui/main/account/NewAccountDialog  at
>   net.java.sip.communicator.plugin.simpleaccreg.SimpleAccountRegistrationActivator$LoginFrame$1.actionPerformed(SimpleAccountRegistrationActivator.java:302)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.main.account.NewAccountDialog not
>   found by net.java.sip.communicator.plugin.simpleaccreg [155]  at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1988)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  ... 37 more

Comment: Then you should show how you are caling that method

Answer (score 0):

Jiti using OSGI framework with Apache Felix Client.So basically when you apply run command on build.xml it will creates bundle of jars.

Now NoClassDefFoundError rises when class is available at Compile time but not available at Run Time. So, due to packaging of jars they both class will go in different jars.So,this error rises.

Solution : Now guess Error is thrown by Class A by importing outside Class B.

```
       find Class A's parent package and search for its manifest file if you are not able to find its manifest file than go to parent of that package. Continue this steps until you find its manifest file.
       In manifest file import package of Class B.

       find Class B's parent package and search for its manifest file if you are not able to find its manifest file than go to parent of that package. Continue this steps until you find its manifest file. 
       In manifest file export package of Class B.

 there are some rules for editing manifest file. So,before editing please read it .
```